# Unusual behaviour of Z3py optimization program

Tags: python, optimization, z3py, quantitative-finance

I'm writing a program that scrapes option_chain data off the [TMX website](https://www.m-x.ca/en/trading/data/quotes?symbol=ZUT*) and suggests an optimized Covered Call options portfolio based on those data. for the optimization process, I used the z3py library as discussed on this website by many users. the optimization process works by maximizing the premiums and setting the portfolio delta to a user-specified amount.

initially, I made a mistake in my calculation for portfolio delta which made everything work so smoothly but I'm facing issues after correcting it. portfolio delta is calculated by taking the Weighted average delta of non-zero positions in the portfolio. to achieve this I used the following setup:

```
eng = Optimize()
Weights = [Real(row.symbol) for row in df.itertuples()]
#to count non-zero positions
TotCount = Real("TotCount")
eng.add(TotCount == Sum([If(w > 0, 1, 0) for w in Weights]))
eng.add(TotCount == If(TotCount >= 0, TotCount, 1))
#to get portfolio delta
eng.add(TotDelta == (Sum([(w * row.delta) for w, row in zip(Weights, df.itertuples())]) / TotCount))
eng.add(TotDelta == delta)
res = eng.check()
```

the weird behavior happens when I run this as a function in a loop with different values for delta, the first loop actually does the calculation and spits out an answer but after that my code gets stuck on the last line for hours without any progress. i tried a few things like completely reformatting it but nothing seems to make a difference. I was wondering if anyone knows what's happening here or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't much in your description for anyone to go on without knowing further details of your setup. All one can deduce from your text is that the constraints are hard to solve for those values of `delta` where it takes longer. Without seeing the rest of your program, it's impossible to opine on what else might be going on.

See if you can isolate the value of delta that it runs slowly on, and just run it for that one instance separately to see if there's interaction coming from elsewhere. That's by no means a solution of course, but it's one way to get started.

One thing I noticed, though, is this line you have:

```py
eng.add(TotCount == If(TotCount >= 0, TotCount, 1))
```

Let's see what this line is saying: If `TotCount >= 0`, then it says `TotCount == TotCount`. i.e., it puts no restrictions on it. Otherwise, it says `TotCount == 1`; i.e., if `TotCount < 0`, then `TotCount == 1`. Well this latter statement is obviously false. That is if, the other constraints force `TotCount < 0`, then your program would be `unsat`. This essentially means that whole line is functionally equivalent to:

```py
eng.add(TotCount >= 0)
```

It's hard for anyone to tell if that's what you intended; but I suspect perhaps it isn't; since you'd have just written the simpler form above. Perhaps you wanted to say something more along the lines of if `TotCount < 0`, then make it `1`. But looking at the previous line, (i.e., the `Sum` expression), we see that this'll never be the case. So, something is fishy there.

Hope that helps to get you started; note that you *cannot* model "sequential assignment" like in a programming language in this way. (You'd need to do what's known as single static assignment, a.k.a. SSA, conversion.) But then again, without knowing your exact intention, it's hard to opine.

Comment: the line you mentioned is my attempt at getting the number of elements with non-zero weights (options to invest in) to get the weighted average of delta. since i need to divide the sum of (weight * delta) by total count, i used that line to avoid dividing by zero (0/1 instead of 0/0, 0/1 is still 0) (3rd line from last). hope this provided more clarity on my intent.  after changing the line to what you mentioned I'm still getting the same results. thank you for that ill look into it.

Comment: i suspect that the problem is from me trying to get the weighted average by, on excel this was incredibly simple and when i ran a test with solver, it found a solution in a matter of seconds. if you feel like my full code can give a better idea please lmk!

Comment: So, you're trying to model regular assignment in a programming language. But what you wrote does *not* do that. You need to create a new variable and use that instead. (i.e., `TotCount1 = If(TotCount >= 0, TotCount, 1)`, and then use `TotCount1`.

Comment: It's best to get the semantics correct first, and then worry about performance; obviously.

Comment: thank you for that, ill make the change in hope that it gets better. sorry, i have less than 2 days of experience using z3py I'm not familiar with a lot of things surrounding it.

Comment: No need to be sorry! This is what stack-overflow is for. Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers